# Number of files deleted from batch file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, command, cmd

```
REM Detect how many files are on the C: drive
dir /s /b C:\ |find /c "\" > NUMfiles.###
set /p count1=<NUMfiles.###

##### TEMP FILES DELETED HERE, RUN CCLEANER, RUN MBAM, ETC #####

REM Calculate Total Files Deleted
dir /s /b C:\ |find /c "\" > NUMfiles.###
set /p count2=<NUMfiles.###
set /a count3=%count1% - %count2%
echo Number of files removed: %count3%
```

This doesn't seem to be giving me an accurate reading. Can anyone help?
I do a manual check via command line using the 'dir /s /b C:\ |find /c "\"' before the script, and at the end. And the output from '%count3% isn't accurate from my subtraction from the manual checks. Hope you understand my question.

Comment: @Methical - it works for me? I deleted one file, count3 was 1. I'd suggest you get a diff on your first and last "dir /s /b C:\"

Comment: Yeah course theres a different, but the difference doesn't match up what the output of the batch file is compared to my subtractions from the "dir /s /b C:\" manually before and after the script has run. I just got a return value of 2. And I visually saw many temp files deleted thru the batch file.

Comment: Just added a second version which should works better at counting files. Could you check it out ?

Comment: As an aside, I'm interested in how you use output redirection and set /p to capture the output of a command to an environment string. I always for /f to do this. Mine is a bit esoteric, but it doesn't create a disk file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as snemarch montined, the fact that you list everything and temporary files could as well be added/deleted by another process meanwhile invalidate the entire effort.

On a side note, adding "/a-d" to the "dir" command would remove the directories from being listed, thus not needing VonC's "find /v "" addition to the process, if you insist on checking files only.

Could you not check file while they get deleted instead? Not sure what you use this for but you definately need to rethink the way from source, the deleting part.

My suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you must iterate on the all content, this command line might be more precise to list the number of *files* (files, not directories):

```
dir /a /s /OG C:\ |find /v "<DIR>" | find /c "M "
```

Off course, this assume a `dir` does display '`AM` ' or '`PM` '.

If it does not, the following should works better:

```
dir /a /s /OG C:\ |find /v "<DIR>" | find /c "/"
```

Comment: I don't think that is correct. I got a return value of 8630? I'm sure there is more files than that on the C: drive. Thanks for your help =)